# Average life time of an element in the stack

Tags: c, algorithm, stack

I came across the following question:

> Let S be a stack of size n >= 1. Starting with the empty stack, suppose we push the first n natural numbers in sequence, and then perform n pop operations. Assume that Push and Pop operation take X seconds each, and Y seconds elapse between the end of one such stack operation and the start of the next operation. For m >= 1, define the stack-life of m as the time elapsed from the end of Push(m) to the start of the pop operation that removes m from S. The average stack-life of an element of this stack is

The answer to the question is supposedly `n(X+Y)-X`.

I don't understand why.Could somebody please explain?

My approach to the question:
Finding out the average life time of any object in the stack is equivalent to finding the life of the middle element of the stack, which in this case would be `n/2`.

if you consider `n` to be odd, then `n/2` perfectly divides the list

the time elapsed between just adding the middle element to the time the nth element is  added is n/2(X+Y)

time elapsed between pushing nth element and popping it is `Y`

time elapsed between popping all the elements until next operation is popping of the `n/2` th element (inclusive of the waiting time between operations i.e `Y`), is `n/2(X+Y)`

`Total time = (n/2)(X+Y)+Y`

Could some one also point out where I went wrong in my approach?

Thanks

Comment: Does the lifetime begin/end at the beginning or at the end of the push/pop? I mean that when `n=1` is lifetime of the element considered to be `Y`, `X+Y`, `Y+X` or `X+Y+X`?

Comment: Just out of couriosity: Why one wants to know this?

Comment: Both push and pop take time and there is an interval between both. You seem to count only the time it takes to push (that's why you get half the time).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To find the average lifetime for an element you should sum the lifetimes of all elements and then divide this result by the number of elements. So: the lifetime of the last element `n` is `Y` as it is popped just after being pushed. The lifetime of the second to last(`n-1`) is `Y + X + Y + X + Y` - the time needed to push and then pop `n` plus two pauses `Y` each. Going forward lets denote A<sub>i</sub> the lifetime of the i-th element. Then `A`<sub>`i`</sub>`=Y + X + A`<sub>`i+1`</sub>`+ Y + X`(adding `Y` and `X` for the push and the pop of A<sub>i+1</sub>).

So we have the sum:

```
Y + (Y + X + Y + X + Y) + (Y + X + (Y + X + Y + X + Y) + X + Y) ..... =
Y + 2 * (Y + X) + Y + 4 * (Y + X) + Y + 6 * (Y + X) + Y + ... 2 *(n - 1) * (Y + X) + Y =
n * Y + 2 * (Y + X) * (1 + 2 + ... (n - 1)) =
n * Y + 2 * (Y + X) * ((n - 1) * n) / 2 =
n * (Y + (n - 1) * (Y + X)) =
n * (n * Y + (n - 1) * X) =
n * (n * (Y + X) - X)
```

Then when you divide this value by n you get just the value expected.

As for where you are going wrong: one error I see is that you state that:

> the time elapsed between just adding the middle element to the time the nth element is added is n/2(X+Y)

While in fact the time required for this is `(n/2 - 1)(X+Y)`. I chose my approach to solve the problem to avoid considering different cases if n is odd or even.